# MySQL server is getting crashed with error no - 0xe06d7363

Tags: mysql, crash

Mysql server getting crashed frequently with below exception, not getting exact cause of crash, Any recommendation or help would be much appreciated !

MySQL version is 5.7.17 and Windows server 2012 R2 standerds

> ```
> 04:31:03 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xe06d7363 ;
> This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
> or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
> or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
> Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
> As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
> collection process might fail.
>
> key_buffer_size=304087040
> read_buffer_size=65536
> max_used_connections=610
> max_threads=1600
> thread_count=498
> connection_count=498
> It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
> key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 828410 K  bytes of memory
> Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
>
> Thread pointer: 0x0
> Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
> where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
> terribly wrong...
> 7ffd7254908c    KERNELBASE.dll!RaiseException()
> 7ff77ee1f407    mysqld.exe!my_wildcmp_mb()
> 7ff77ee574c1    mysqld.exe!my_wildcmp_mb()
> 7ff77ec26365    mysqld.exe!?reserve@?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAAX_K@Z()
> 7ff77ec257a0    mysqld.exe!?reserve@?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAAX_K@Z()
> 7ff77ec2ac08    mysqld.exe!?reserve@?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAAX_K@Z()
> 7ff77ec2a923    mysqld.exe!?reserve@?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAAX_K@Z()
> 7ff77ecccb4c    mysqld.exe!?reserve@?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAAX_K@Z()
> 7ff77eccd7f2    mysqld.exe!?reserve@?$vector@EV?$allocator@E@std@@@std@@QEAAX_K@Z()
> 7ffd735c13d2    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
> 7ffd752254f4    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
> The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
> ```

Comment: From MySQL Command Prompt, what is result of SELECT @@thread_cache_size; ?

Comment: SELECT @@thread_cache_size; output is 10